# Is OjAlgo eigenvalues always on descended order?

Tags: java, ojalgo

When computing the eigenvalues with OjAlgo. Are the eigenvalues always on a descended order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the documentation for [`Eigenvalue#isOrdered`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/ojAlgo/org/ojalgo/matrix/decomposition/Eigenvalue.html#isOrdered--):

> The eigenvalues in D (and the eigenvectors in V) are not necessarily ordered. This is a property of the algorithm/implementation, not the data.

Comment: So "This is a property of the algorithm" means that they are functionality that sort on descended order? I don't understand the answer.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Your question is: *"Are the eigenvalues always on a descended order?"*, and the answer is: *"The eigenvalues [...] are not necessarily ordered"*.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson There is one more thing: Check out [`Eigenvalue#getEigenvalues`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/ojAlgo/org/ojalgo/matrix/decomposition/Eigenvalue.html#getEigenvalues--): *"The values should be in the same order as the matrices "V" and "D", and if they are ordered or not is indicated by the isOrdered() method."*

Comment: And it's a property of the algorithm/implementation...not the data. So if the algorithm is selected on a descended order...then the result must be on descended order as well?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Sorry, I'm not to sure at this point myself. As you've noticed, the documentation is kinda ambiguous and I don't want to tell you wrong things. You should probably just try it out or wait for another answer.

Comment: What does "if the algorithm is selected on a descended order" mean? The method isOrdered() will tell you if the eigenvalues are guaranteed to be ordered or not.

Comment: @apete I was confused due to the word `property` in `This is a property of the algorithm/implementation`. It's like a random algorithm was implemented that sort on descended order if it wants.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the algorithm chosen for computing the eigenvalues. For instance, in the class `RawEigenvalue.Symmetric`, `isOrdered()` returns true. According to my limited understanding, this particular decomposition is used when the matrix is real, symmetric, and not too big (and possibly in other cases).